# POST to docker container inside Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

On AWS, I've configured a Lambda function based on a docker image (uploaded on ECR). The image starts an express (node) server listening on port 8080. How can I reach that server from the public Lambda function url (so outside via https) with a POST request? Do I need other AWS service, or just a Lambda config? Thanks.

Comment: Did you use one of the base Lambda images to create your container? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html Does your container implement the AWS Lambda runtime interface? AWS Lambda is not a generic container runner, it only supports containers that can handle requests via the Lambda runtime interface.

Comment: I'm using a custom image based on https://hub.docker.com/r/surnet/alpine-node-wkhtmltopdf/. Reading the container logs on cloudwatch, I know for sure that the Lambda is being executed, but I don't know how to POST to it.

Comment: You can't POST to it unless it implements the Lambda runtime interface. That docker image you based it on does not implement the Lambda runtime interface. If you posted to an AWS Lambda function  URL, Lambda would try to send that post data as an event, to an interface that does not exist in your container.